# Every probability measure on a metric space is regular

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

In [Billingsley's book](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316962) Theorem 1 says the following:

*Let $S$ be a metric space equipped with the metric $\rho$ and be $\mathcal{S}$ be the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-field. Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathcal{S}$. Then $\mu$ is regular in the sense that, for all $A\in\mathcal{S}$ and for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exist sets $F$ closed and $G$ open such that $F\subset A\subset G$ and $\mu(G-F)<\varepsilon$.*

Proof.
Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the class of sets of $\mathcal{S}$ such that the claimed property holds. The proof proceeds in two steps. First it is proved that if $A$ is closed then $A\in\mathcal{G}$ and then that $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then the proof is completed because, being $\mathcal{S}$ generated by all closed sets, then it must be $\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{S}$.

My problem is not in the first part, but in the second, when we try to prove that $\mathcal{G}$ is a sigma-algebra. The author considers a sequence of set $A_n\in\mathcal{G}$, so that there must exist sets $F_n$ closed and $G_n$ open such that $F_n\subset A_n\subset G_n$ and $\mu(G_n-F_n)<\varepsilon/2^{n+1}$. Then he considers $G=\bigcup_nG_n$, which is open and $F=\bigcup_{n\leq n_0}F_n$, which is closed, with $n_0$ such that $\mu(\bigcup_{n}F_n-\bigcup_{n\leq n_0}F_n)<\varepsilon/2$.
The final claim is that
$$
F\subset \bigcup_n A_n \subset G\text{ and }\mu(G-F)<\varepsilon.
$$
First, I would put $\bigcup_n A_n \subseteq G$, because the union is taken upon an infinite number of sets so: shouldn't we consider the possibility that they are the same? Second, I cannot figure out why $\mu(G-F)<\varepsilon$. Any suggestions? I guess there is some set identity to be exploited, but I cannot see which is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\mu(G\setminus F) = \mu\left(\bigcup_n G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n\leq n_0}F_n\right)<\mu\left(\bigcup_n G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n}F_n\right) + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
since the following set inclusion holds:
$$\bigcup_n G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n\leq n_0}F_n \subseteq \left(\bigcup_n G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n}F_n\right) \cup \left(\bigcup_{n}F_n \setminus \bigcup_{n\leq n_0}F_n \right) $$

Now just verify that
$$\bigcup_n G_n \setminus \bigcup_{n}F_n \subseteq \bigcup_n (G_n\setminus F_n)$$

As for the strict inclusions, I think even in the statement of the theorem you need them (take for example $A=S$ or $A=\emptyset$).